# Why subsetting in different ways in R does not always return a numeric?

Tags: r, subset, tidyverse

I have a time series of data (5 columns of time series - everyone is double data type – with a column of dates) stored into a tibble called `db`. I noticed the following behaviour:

- When I call `is.numeric(db[,5])` I get FALSE
- When I call `is.numeric(db$colname)` I get TRUE – with colname being the column name of the 5 column
- When I call `is.finite(db$colname)` I get all TRUE

However, the different behaviour of calling a column with `db[,5]` cause some troubles, especially related to some plotting functions. For instance, calling `hist(db[,5])`  return `Error in hist.default(db1[, 5]) : 'x' must be numeric.` 
Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour and a workaround to keep using the subsetting method of `db[,5]` at the same time avoiding the issue that the extracted list must be numeric?

Comment: can you post the result of `dput(head(db))` inside your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because unlike dataframes `tibbles` do not drop their dimensions when a single column is subsetted. See this example, to understand

```
df <- mtcars %>% as_tibble()

is.numeric(df$mpg) #Check class(df$mpg)
#[1] TRUE 

is.numeric(df[, 1]) #Check class(df[, 1])
#[1] FALSE
```

You can use `[[` to get the output as vector and hence output to `is.numeric` as `TRUE`

```
is.numeric(df[[1]]) #Check class(df[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```

However, note that

```
is.numeric(mtcars[,1])
#[1] TRUE
```

That is because as explained earlier.

```
class(df[, 1])
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

as opposed to

```
class(mtcars[, 1])
#[1] "numeric"
```